# ¿Cómo hacer que una app tenga un botón para deshabilitar sus propias notificaciones?

Tags: android, push-notification

Lo que me gustaría hacer es un `Button` que hiciera lo mismo que hace android en las propias notificaciones que permite que no se muestren de una app concreta, en este caso la mía. ¿Es posible?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ¿Cómo hacer que una app tenga un botón para deshabilitar sus propias
>   notificaciones?

Para que tu aplicación no reciba `Push Notifications`, en este caso tu debes implementar que se realice el desregistro para que dejes de recibir notificaciones.

Anteriormente se usaba el método [unregister()](https://web.archive.org/web/20170715184654/https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging#unregister()) el cual es obsoleto:

> Este metodo es obsoleto. En su lugar use `InstanceID.deleteToken()` o
>   `InstanceID.deleteInstanceID()`.

Debes usar [deleteInstanceID()](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/guides/android-implementation#delete_tokens_and_product_names) :

```
InstanceID.getInstance(context).deleteInstanceID();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Sin ver tu codigo no te puedo decir exactamente donde tienes que poner que y como, pero te doy varias ideas:

Creas una configuracion (Setting) que sea un boleano de notificacion si/no.

Dependiendo de como de radical quieres que sea el no permiso de notificaciones puedes hacer:

Que en el momento que el usuario activa que no quiere notificaciones lo desregistre del servicio de notificaciones, y al entrar en la app, si compruebas si esta registrado o no, si el setting es no notificaciones, entonces no lo desregistra.

Si necesitas que el usuario reciba los datos de la notificacion, pero solo quieres que no se le muestre (por que esos datos los añades a la app, como un mensaje de otro usuario, por ejemplo), en el codigo que recibe la notificacion haces la gestion de datos, y dependiendo del setting lanzas la notificacion o no.